# Is it more efficient to use "import <module>" or "from <module> import <func>"?

Tags: python, import

Say I only needed to use findall() from the re module, is it more efficient to do:

```
from re import findall
```

or

```
import re
```

Is there actually any difference in speed/memory usage etc?

Comment: Premature optimization is evil.  Please provide some specific thing to optimize.  Blanket "is more efficient" questions are meaningless without a specific piece of code to measure.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no difference on the import, however there is a small difference on access.

When you access the function as

```
re.findall()
```

python will need to first find the module in the global scope and then find findall in modules dict.  May make a difference if you are calling it inside a loop thousands of times.

Comment: +1, but also note that Python will search local namespace before global namespaces, so creating a local function (findall = re.findall) that references the function is the best, and works identically with both import styles.

Answer (score 16):

When in doubt, time it:

```
from timeit import Timer

print Timer("""re.findall(r"\d+", "fg12f 1414 21af 144")""", "import re").timeit()
print Timer("""findall(r"\d+", "fg12f 1414 21af 144")""", "from re import findall").timeit()
```

I get the following results, using the minimum of 5 repetitions of 10,000,000 calls:

```
re.findall(): 123.444600105
findall(): 122.056155205
```

There appears to be a very slight usage advantage to using `findall()` directly, rather than `re.findall()`.

However, the actual import statements differ in their speed by a significant amount. On my computer, I get the following results:

```
>>> Timer("import re").timeit()
2.39156508446
>>> Timer("from re import findall").timeit()
4.41387701035
```

So `import re` appears to be approximately twice as fast to execute. Presumably, though, execution of the imported code is your bottleneck, rather than the actual import.

Comment: I think it is also best to study the difference in terms of memory loads to accompany the timing.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference, except for what names from re are visible in you local namespace after the import.